# I'm trying to apply css style file but Django not recognizing it

Tags: python, html, css, django

this is the base.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{%load static%}
<html lang="en">
   
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block page_title %}my challenges{% endblock  %}</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "style.css"%}">    
    {%block css_files%} {%endblock%}
</head> 

<body>
    
    {% block content %}
    
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

2. challenges.css

```css
ul{
    list-style: circle;
    margin: 2rem auto;
    width: 90% ;
    max-width: 50rem;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 1px;

}
```

3. index.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{%block css_files%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "challenges/challenges.css" %}">
{%endblock%}

{%block page_title%}
    All chalenges
{%endblock%}

{%block content%}
{% include "challenges/includes/header.html"  %}
    <ul>
        {% for month in months%}
            <li><a href="{% url "month-challenge" month %}">{{month|title}}</a></li> 
        {% endfor %}   
    </ul>
 
{%endblock%}
```

[path is here in the image[][1]][1]
[see the image styles are not applying ][2]
please help me on this I've already added the path and everything on setting.py also

```
STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static"
]
```

You can see the flow diagram here :
[image]

Comment: Show us the structure of the project (where are the CSS files located and so on). Also I think you have typo in `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "style.css"%}">`, it should be **styles**, not **style**, like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "styles.css"%}"> `

Comment: but the problem with the chalenges.css. The style.css that you have mentioned is working fine.

Comment: Again...please show the structure of the project...

Comment: I've edited the Question here. You can go over and check it out.